# How to get ClientRectangle and DisplayRectangle in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have placed a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Scrollview into a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel in UWP.
Now I'm trying to get the DisplayRectangle and ClientRectangle using C#.

I know that this is possible in .Net Framework with C#.

```
Rectangle client = ClientRectangle;
Rectangle displayRectangle = _displayRect;
```

I want to do the same in UWP. Is this possible in UWP? If not, Is there a way around to get those two info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get ClientRectangle and DisplayRectangle in UWP

There is no such property in UWP platform. For your requirement, you could add Border to your `RelativePanel` to `indicate` the Display area.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name= "Test" >

    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

For `ClientRectangle`, you could call `Content` property to get the client area.

```
var content =  Test.Content;
```

Comment: ClientRectangle returns a Rectangle object. Therefore we can get its width and height of it. But In "var content =  Test.Content;" Can we access those variables?

Comment: No, you can't get Rectangle with `Test.Content`, if you want to get the size of content, please call ScrollViewer  `Extentheight` `ExtentWidth`. for more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.extentheight).